# comma separated checkbox values

Tags: php, checkbox, get

Does anyone know how to output checkboxes value in a comma separated way?
Lets assume that I have 2 checkboxes:

- `<input id="filetype_photo" name="type" type="checkbox" value="photo" >`
- `<input id="filetype_graphic" name="type" type="checkbox" value="graphic" >`

If I retrieve them with $_GET I get the following url:

- sitename.com?type=photo&type=graphic
  My goal is to get the following url if both checkboxes are selected:
- sitename.com?type=photo,graphic

I have tried using array of checkboxes renaming them to name[] and using the following function to litertae trough the results:

```
$type=$_GET['type'];
while (list ($key,$val) = @each ($type)) {
echo $val;
}
```

but this gives me the checkboxes values but does not solve the url problem. Moreover, the urls gets messed up by changing
type=photo to &type%5B%5D=photo

Any ideas?

P.S. I need to work it out server side

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
<input id="filetype_photo" name="type[]" type="checkbox" value="photo" >
<input id="filetype_graphic" name="type[]" type="checkbox" value="graphic" >
```

And your `$type=$_GET['type']` will be an array.

Answer (score 1):

PHP can't deal with multiple parameters with the same name unless they end with square brackets. You will need to parse the query string manually if you want to avoid using them.

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript to compile a comma seperated string of values and the redirect with window.location

Comment: Then use name="type[]" for both checkboxs. then the url should be fine as well as your itteration receiving the array

Comment: The itteration works fine, I receive the values from both checkboxes with the name name[]. The problem is how to force the form not to output two values of each checkbox to url but to output the comma separated array of them? I thought about using hidden input field and passing array value to its value yet that seems to be bad practice and not realla solution

Comment: Yeh, I get what your saying. I just dont't get why the type[]=photo in the url would be a problem for you though. I guess I agree with @Ignacio then :)